# How to automatically mirror local git to web hosting

Tags: git, version-control, hosting, web-hosting

Suppose I have a local repository, `project` and just made some changes to it.

On my server I have:

```
Project
   |- index.html
   |- about.html
```

If I make changes to the local repository, and add a new file, say `style.css`, is there a way to automatically make the changes to the server so that this happens after I make the local changes:

```
Project
   |- index.html
   |- about.html
   |- style.css
```

The idea is that a lot of my work from this project is going to be online for others to show. So far, I've been uploading and re-writing manually through FTP to put the files up. I was wondering if there was a tool/app/script that would help automate this process - if not in Git, perhaps some kind of FTP tool?

I am using justhost if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what git is for,

Making your changes and then commit and share it.
Follow those steps to set up your repository:

1. open an account in any git server
2. create a new repository
3. follow the instructions on those sites
4. set up you local repository
5. push your code to the remote repository

---

A collection of resources to learn git from:
https://help.github.com/articles/good-resources-for-learning-git-and-github/